# How obtain resource by name using locale only?

Tags: android

In my application I have some resource strings that depend on the translation.
The availability of these strings depends from the translation (they work like constants).

I obtain it using `getResources.getIdentifier(name, "string", getContext().getPackageName());`

The problem is due to the default strings (English) define the values for the local translation and it affects to the other translations.

For example:

`en` translation defines `value_17` and `es` translation doesn't. But when I'm using `es` and I try to get string `value_17` I get the English value.

Can I get only the `value_17` if defined in local translation? (`es` in this case)

Answer (score 0):

That's not offered via the API, but you can easily achieve it.

First move all the English strings into an en locale.  Then make all the default strings empty.  Now when you ask for an es string, you will either get the es specific version, or the empty default one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the way but If I use it I loss the default language, I think; and is not a good idea.